# Why do my answers randomize in my Quiz Game?

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode

I made a Quiz Game in Swift 2 last year, now I need to use it again when I converted it to Swift 3 the answers randomize now... Here is a sample Question Structure...

```
Questions = [Question(Question: "What is the Biggest Hit of Bing Crosby?" , Answers: ["Swinging on a Star", "Now is the Hour", "White Christmas", "Beautiful Dreamer"], Answer: 2),]
```

This is where I randomize the questions and put them into the labels

```
func PickQuestions() {

    counter += 1
    score += 1
    scoreLbl.text = "\(score)"

    restartBtn.isEnabled = false
    if Questions.count > 0 && counter <= 15 {
        QNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(Questions.count)))
        QLabel.text = Questions[QNumber].Question

        AnswerNumber = Questions[QNumber].Answer

        for i in 0..<Buttons.count{
            Buttons[i].setTitle(Questions[QNumber].Answers[i], for: UIControlState())
        }

        Questions.remove(at: QNumber)
    }
}
```

I had to change the following line manually which may have caused an issue from...

```
QNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(Questions.count)))
```

to

```
QNumber = random() % Questions.count
```

Thanks

Comment: You should stick to Swift programming standards/naming convention. Variables shouldn't be capitalized, and should be camel case. To us, all of your variables look like classes and could confuse us because then we think those classes might be manipulating the data somehow and we wouldn't know. If it's not a class, enum, typealias, protocol, or struct, don't capitalize them.

Answer (score -1):

Arrays are unordered collections, meaning that their order could potentially change without your knowing. Your best bet would be to create a single array containing a struct that holds both the question and answer, like so:

```
struct QuizItem {
    var question: String!
    var answer: String!
    var answerOptions: [String]!

    init(q: String, a: String, aOptions:[String]) {
         self.question = q
         self.answer = a   
    }
}
```

Change your declaration to look like the following:
`let items = [QuizItem(...)]`

Your code like this:

```
func PickQuestions() {

    counter += 1
    score += 1
    scoreLbl.text = "\(score)"

    restartBtn.isEnabled = false
    if items.count > 0 && counter <= 15 {
        QNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(Questions.count)))
        let item = items[QNumber]
        QLabel.text = item.question

        for i in 0..<Buttons.count{
            Buttons[i].setTitle(item.answerOptions[i], for: UIControlState())
        }

        items.remove(at: QNumber)
    }
}
```

Also, kind of picky but worth highlighting still. Swift is a **camel case** language and although this rule isn't set in stone, you should try and stick to the widely recognised coding practices.

Comment: Are you sure about your first sentence? Or did you mean when passed as a parameter? Or in what circumstance will the array randomly shuffle? I've never had an array not be ordered how I wanted it and I've used Swift since it came out.